# Getting an on-screen (onboard) keyboard to work on ubuntu20

Tags: onscreen-keyboard, onboard

I just got an Ubuntu 20.04.2 installed and need to change keyboard often, between English, Russian, German and Danish.  The are no results from searching for it ("no results" when asking for "onboard", "on-screen keyboard") in the given software. Can someone help with this?

Comment: Well, I thought it was enough with "20" to refer to the the newest possible desktop version for Ubuntu.  I do not know how to find that information, but I remember it being called 20.04.3 when I downloaded it.

Comment: I don't know how to check my version.

Comment: I found out that the OS is Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS 64 bit with GNOME version 3.36.8 - does that help?